# NGINX auth_request is ignored

Tags: nginx

I have the following in my nginx.conf:

```
location / {
    auth_request /auth;
    add_header Content-Type text/plain;
    return 200 'You are in!';
}

location = /auth {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5021/auth;
    proxy_pass_request_body off;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
    proxy_pass_header Authorization;
}
```

Thus I would expect `http://localhost:5021/auth` (a Flask app) to be accessed upon trying to reach `/`. This does not happen, and using the `nginx-debug` binary and `error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;` I never see any of the debug output that [I expect to see](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/src/http/modules/ngx_http_auth_request_module.c) (log for the request is available [here](https://pastebin.com/FLx2UjNz)). There are no errors, neither printed to the console nor any of nginx's log files. It seems like the `auth_request` line is just silently ignored.

Output of `nginx-debug -V` (it does contain `--with-http_auth_request_module`):

```
nginx version: nginx/1.15.8
built by gcc 6.4.0 (Alpine 6.4.0) 
built with OpenSSL 1.0.2q  20 Nov 2018
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_xslt_module=dynamic --with-http_image_filter_module=dynamic --with-http_geoip_module=dynamic --with-threads --with-stream --with-stream_ssl_module --with-stream_ssl_preread_module --with-stream_realip_module --with-stream_geoip_module=dynamic --with-http_slice_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-compat --with-file-aio --with-http_v2_module --with-debug
```

Comment: I have the same issue on nginx/1.16.0

Comment: I have the same issue as well, version 1.16.0. Did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 6):

[return](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#return) will unconditionally stop the processing and return the specified code to a client, you probably want to remove that.

Comment: I would add, that an alternative could be setting an "Alias" directive to a static file, containing what you wanted to put in the return value. ('You are in!'). just make sure the alias won't give unneeded access to some directory.

Answer (score 4):

There's a few things that may be affecting the configuration from working properly.

- The first being the `internal` directive should be included in `/auth`.
- Secondly a **NULL** `Content-Length` should be initialized.
- Thirdly `$host` vs `$http_host` is important; incorrect requests won't be passed (see below)
- Another consideration would be including a trailing `/` after the last path of the URI
  <sub>(I noticed the docs show the URI this way if it's depth > 1).</sub>

*An unchanged “Host” request header field can be passed like this:*

> <sub>**proxy_set_header Host $http_host;**</sub>
>
> <sub>However, if this field is not
>   present in a client request header then nothing will be passed. In
>   such a case it is better to use the $host variable - its value equals
>   the server name in the “Host” request header field or the primary
>   server name if this field is not present:</sub>
>
> <sub>**proxy_set_header Host $host;**</sub>
>
> <sub>In addition, the server name can be
>   passed together with the port of the proxied server:</sub>
>
> <sub>**proxy_set_header Host $host:$proxy_port;**</sub>

The configuration should end up looking similar to the following:

```
location / {
    auth_request /auth;
    auth_request_set $auth_status $upstream_status;
}

location = /auth {
    internal;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5021/auth/;
    proxy_pass_request_body off;
    proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
    proxy_pass_header Authorization;
}
```

Comment: I don't have time to try your suggestions until the bounty expires, but your answer is nonetheless elaborate and of high quality

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks absolutely correct and there is no error with the `return` statement.
The `auth_request` module is available in `nginx` since `version 1.5.4` but it is not compiled by default.

Please check if your installed version of `nginx` was compiled with `auth_request` support using the following command:

```
nginx -V 2>&1 | grep -qF -- --with-http_auth_request_module && echo "Module Compiled" || echo "Not Compiled"
```

If it is `Not Compiled`, then this module is not built by default, thus it should be enabled with the `--with-http_auth_request_module` configuration parameter as below:

```
./configure --with-http_auth_request_module
```

Reload nginx service using 
    `service nginx reload` and hit `http://localhost` again.
This should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 127.0.0.1;

    location / {
        return 200 "You are in!";
    }
}

server {
    srever_name ...;

    location / {
        auth_request /auth;

        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        ...

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:80;
}

location = /auth {
    internal;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5021/auth/;
    ...
}
```

or

```
location / {
    auth_request /auth;

    try_files notExistsfile @verified;
}

location @verified {
    internal;
    return 200 "You are in!";
}
```

Comment: I think this is explained by @dusan-bajic, that return will unconditionally stop the processing ...

Answer (score -3):

Instead

```
return 200 'You are in!';
```

you can use the following code

```
echo -n "You are in!";
```

Comment: but I don't know what may use instead

```
return 303 /some_uri;
```

Comment: This can only be used when the `echo-nginx-module` is enabled, which is part of `OpenResty`.